# Simultaneous observations in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, relative-motion

Consider an object which responds to two different signals A and B: it responds to signal A with blue color and signal B with red color.  Also, it responds only to the signal that reached first. In case they both reach together, there is no observation.

Now consider three observers $x,y,\,z$. If event that both signals reaches at the same time for $x$, then for $y$ and $z$ there must exist velocity $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that these signals aren't simultaneous to them. Let for $y$ A reached first and for $z$ B reached first. Then what will be the actual color the object emits?

Comment: An event is always simultaneous with itself, regardless of who does the measuring.

Answer (score 0):

Events that happen at the same time *and the same position* in one inertial frame happen simultaneously in *all* inertial frames, you can easily verify this just by looking at how the Lorentz transformation creates a one-to-one relation between spacetime coordinates in one frame and spacetime coordinates in any other frame. It's only if events occur at *different* positions in space that you can have a situation where one frame says the two events were simultaneous and other frames say they weren't. So if your "object" is at a single point in space when two signals reach it simultaneously in one frame, then all frames agree the signals reached it simultaneously.